# Checking if object key exists and is true in one statement

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a javascript object that may or may not contain a certain key which may or may not be true;

```
{
    myKey: true,
}
```

I want to test whether the key exists, and if it does exist, whether it is true. I could do it like this;

```
if (myObject.myKey == true) {
}
```

With the use of the loose equality operator `==`, the answer will be false if `myKey` is undefined or false and only true if it is true. However, eslint complains `'Expected '===' and instead saw '=='. eslint(eqeqeq)'`. Is this a valid warning, or should I just ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `==` operator has many surprises, which is why eslint is discouraging it. In this case, what eslint suggests does exactly what you're asking for:

```
if (myObject.myKey === true) {
}
```

Differences with the `==` operator only occur here if the value exists and is not a boolean; e.g. the value `1`. Due to the type conversions, `1 == true` is true, but `1 === true` is false.

If you also want a true value for such cases, just write

```
if (myObject.myKey) {
}
```

Comment: Right on the money. Tested it out in chrome console and it does just what I want. Thanks

Comment: Notice that not all truthy values are `== true`. It's probably rare though to want exactly this behaviour.